# Automatically delete post in a single category when a new one is created

Tags: posts, automation

Is it possible to delete/move to trash a post in a single category each time that a new post in the same category is created? I mean, I need to always keep just one post (the most recent) visible in that one category.

Answer (score 0):

Why not. The API of WordPress has the function [`wp_delete_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post) to delete a post. If the trash is active, on default true, then this function moves the post to the trash. 
You need to add a logic after publishing a new post to delete the old one. To firte your function you should use the hook [`publish_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

So a simple starter see below, need the logic to get the ID of the old post.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post349197', 10, 2 );
function post349197( $ID, $post ) {

    // &oldID = Need logic to get the last post.
    wp_delete_post($oldId);
}
```